# PHP Distinct Home Directories

Tags: php, security, iis, include

I am trying to set up a PHP server using IIS but have hit a slight snag.

We will have multiple users with different home directories and, out of the box, User1 can access User2's files using, e.g., include statements by doing:

```
include('..\User2\file.php');
```

Is there any way that I can securely tell PHP to only allow file access below a certain filepath (i.e. User1 can only access their own files under .\User1)?

If not, is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain how you seperate these users? Will they run different instances of IIS, one per user?

Comment: At the moment it is one instance of IIS, that's not to say it has to stay that way.

Separation is done through FTP, different user accounts that point them to their own upload directory with relevant permissions applied using NTFS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I have found the solution...

The file structure is as follows:

D:\wwwroot\User1\
D:\wwwroot\User2\

In php.ini add the following:

```
[PATH=D:/wwwroot/User1/]
open_basedir=D:/wwwroot/User1/

[PATH:=D:/wwwroot/User2]
open_basedir=D:/wwwroot/User2/
```

PHP will then refuse the open files under ../User2/ for User1, and files under ../User1/ for User2.